# Calling a custom profile field only it it exists

Tags: custom-field, author, profiles, author-template

I've used this code to show custom fields if they're filled in a post using Custom Field Suite Plugin

```
<?php if($cfs->get('whatliked')){?>
<?php echo $cfs->get('whatliked'); ?>
<?php   }?>
```

Now I need to have the same check for some custom profile fields I've added through functions.php

```
/* BEGIN Custom User Contact Info */
 function extra_contact_info($contactmethods) {
     unset($contactmethods['aim']);
     unset($contactmethods['yim']);
     unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
     $contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';
     $contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
     $contactmethods['google+'] = 'Google+';
     $contactmethods['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn';
     return $contactmethods;
 }
 add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'extra_contact_info');
 /* END Custom User Contact Info */
```

What is the code I need to add to my author.php to check if the facebook field has been filled and if "yes" then show and if "no" then hide...

P.s.
Is there a way to post the code with linebreaks already in???

Comment: Indent the line four spaces and you get a code block. (There is a Javascript tool-- look for `{}`) See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

On an "author" page you can get a lot of the information you need with `get_queried_object` and additional information with `get_user_meta`. What you want (sounds like) should be in that second chunk of information.That is...

```
$author = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$ameta = get_user_meta($author->ID);

var_dump($author,$ameta); // debugging

if(!empty($ameta['facebook'])) {
  var_dump($ameta['yim']); // debugging
}
// and so one for each contact method that you want to show
```

I am sure that is not how you want the information formatted but that should get you going.